# ES6 module code executed every time it is imported

Tags: karma-runner, ecmascript-6, webpack

Is the code in ES6 modules executed every time we import a module? I'm using webpack and it seems that it does exactly that.

```
// FormStore.js
import sessionActions from "../../session/actions/session";

// session.spec.js
import sessionActions from "../../../src/session/actions/session";

This causes the code in the session module to be executed twice
```

Comment: No, modules are instantiated only once. Can you show an example?

Comment: It seems that this happens only when I run tests through karma. That's a bit strange

Comment: Can you post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: I'm having a multi-evaluation problem with Webpack: https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/2740

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know exactly the answer, but I suspect it has to do with karma. I think it's due to having two different bundles.

In `karma.config`

```
preprocessors: {
    "client/specs/index.ts": ["webpack"],
    "client/specs/**/*spec.ts": ["webpack"]
},

webpack: {
    entry: {
        index: "./client/src/index.tsx",
        vendor: []
    }
},
```

Basically, I don't really need to add the `index` entry point, as this will probably create an additional bundle.

Answer (score 0):

1. Do you want your code to be executed when imported? If in your /session/actions/session files there is a function call being exported rather than function declaration then it will be called when imported in any bundle you created. You can import different modules in different files.
2. If you are using [karma-webpack](https://github.com/webpack/karma-webpack)
   the [usage](https://github.com/webpack/karma-webpack#usage)

tells you that

```
webpack: {
        // karma watches the test entry points
        // (you don't need to specify the entry option)
        // webpack watches dependencies

        // webpack configuration
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

A coworker was experiencing the same issue today- the problem seemed to be caused by two imports of one package, but each import referencedthat package using a different path. You appear to be doing the same thing:

```
// FormStore.js
import sessionActions from "../../session/actions/session"; // note first path

// session.spec.js
import sessionActions from "../../../src/session/actions/session"; // note second path, which is different from first
```

Is it possible for the import in session.spec.js to import using the same path? If this isn't an option due to relative locations of the files, can you configure your module loader so that *sessionActions* is aliased (using `map` or `path`, for instance). I'm not sure if this is an option in your environment, however.

See:
https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs/blob/master/docs/config-api.md#map
for how to do this using system.js